# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hello I am working on an ASP.NET page where I want to view data from database using AJAX

What I have done is created the following C# method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
public static void ViewData(string contNumber, string BookingNo)
{
    if (contNumber != "" && BookingNo != "")
    {
        string container = contNumber;
        string booking = BookingNo;

        db.SelectData(container, booking);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("IN!!"+ booking);
    }
}
```

I then call this method using AJAX, here the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script

        function View() {

            var container = document.getElementById("#<%=contNoTxtBox.ClientID%>").value;
            var booking = document.getElementById("#<%=bookingNoTxtBox.ClientID%>").value;

          //  var cont = container.value;
         //   var book = booking.value;

            $.ajax(
                {

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "VGMForm.aspx/ViewData",
                    data: '{contNumber: "' + $(container) + '", BookingNo: "' + $(booking) + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"

                });


        }
```

From my HTML page I call the function using the following code:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="View()" />
```

However, when I click on the button, I receive the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

I am unsure as to what is causing this error, what is the cause and how can I resolve it?

Comment: what is in contNoTxtBox.ClientID and bookingNoTxtBox.ClientID?

Comment: @AmmarHasan just normal text boxes

Comment: Are you sure that id's are correct, and same as the html rendered?

Comment: @AmmarHasan yes the IDs are exact the same           <asp:TextBox ID="contNoTxtBox" runat="server" Width="182px" style="height: 22px" OnTextChanged="contNoTxtBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: Is there a possibility that this script runs before the these html elements are actually rendered?

Comment: @AmmarHasan i placed it before the body tag where these elements reside.

Comment: Try placing after body tag, at the bottom of the html

Comment: @AmmarHasan i was able to solve by removing the .ClientID in the script XD ...... the answer:      var container = document.getElementById("contNoTxtBox").value;
     var booking = document.getElementById("bookingNoTxtBox").value;   thanx for your help

Comment: You should answer your question yourself here, and mark as answer, so that the topic is closed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by removing the .ClientID from the script as the following:

```
var container = document.getElementById("contNoTxtBox").value;
 var booking = document.getElementById("bookingNoTxtBox").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of `getElementById` returns `null`

```
  document.getElementById("#<%=contNoTxtBox.ClientID%>")
```

or

```
  document.getElementById("#<%=bookingNoTxtBox.ClientID%>")
```

Comment: @DmitsiyLoskutov i tried this way but the response message that put inside the method as test is not displayed. and it seems it doesn't get the value correctly